# Burnination of small tags

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-system

I have come across [github-workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-workflow) and it is only used in [a single question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66037663/10871900).

Since workflows are part of [github-actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-actions) (He also tagged the question with both tags), I decided to [create a synonym request for this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/github-actions/synonyms) as users might want to use that tag to ask questions about [github-actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github-actions).

However, this got me thinking:

What if a tag that is only used by a small number of questions (with `small`, I mean like 1-5 questions) [meets the criterias for burnitation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/10871900)? Does the [normal process of tag burnitation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/10871900) apply here or is it actually appropriate to just remove the tag from the questions without a meta post if there is only a small amount of questions of that tag?

Comment: If you want one tag to be merged wholly into (and/or synonymized with) another existing tag, then this is something you should ask moderators to help with. We can click one button and do this merge, with no mess. I've gone ahead and completed this merge now. In the future, bringing it up on Meta is good; just make clear that you want the tags *merged* (and explain why a merge is appropriate). Moderators will see it that way.

Comment: The guidelines linked elsewhere are for *burninations*, which is the manual cleanup of questions containing the tag, with the ultimate aim of removing the tag from the system. This one doesn't need to be burninated, and doesn't require any manual cleanup.

Comment: I am aware of the difference between synonymizing and burnitation. The question was about burnitation of small tags like that (I chose this tag as an example of a small tag, even if it would not be a canidate for burnitation). Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: It's a [real thing](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions).  SO is not that well served by hi-rep users with powerful moderation rights that know the *old thing*.  Give it a chance to grow and prosper.

Comment: Yes it is a real thing. It is like the main part of GitHub Actions making most questions about GitHub Actions related to workflows.

Comment: OK, understood. It was just a badly chosen example then. Our [burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071) specifically makes an allowance for the case where a tag has a small number of questions, you are knowledgeable about the subject-matter, and you've conferred with someone else knowledgeable. But it's important not to go about manually removing tags when a merge by a moderator would be more effective and efficient.